# Facebook Prophet - running into dying kernel with 'future' dataframe

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, kernel, facebook-prophet

I am using FB Prophet to do a forecasting in Jupyter Notebook using Python 3. My model was working fine, until I decided to split my data up into 'train' and 'test'.

Instead of using 'future = m.make_future_dataframe' I am now doing this:
'future = df_test[['ds']]'

When I make this change, the kernel dies after loading for about 1 minute (Jupyter Notebook). With the old 'future', it loads within a couple of seconds.

This is what my df_test['ds'] looks like:

```
ds
0   2023-09-28
1   2023-09-30
2   2023-10-06
3   2023-10-06
4   2023-10-10
```

As you may notice, not every day is present as my data only has a row created every time a change happens (to reduce data). Is this what is causing the issue? I removed the 'HH, MM, SS' part to make sure it follows YYYY-MM-DD.

Many thanks!

I tried troubleshooting with various things, such as the date formatting, having a 'larger' amount of dates in test etc. The kernel kept dying.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.